# Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.scala.cobertura.CoberturaSensor

Tags: scala, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using SonarQube 5.1 and its running on localhost. It was working out of box for java, but when i added the plugin for scala - http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Scala+Plugin (i checked out the code from github, build the jar and then installed in sonarqube installation), now every time i invoke the gradle command sonarRunner - I am getting this error:

```
19:52:55.232 [ERROR] [system.err] ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
19:52:55.233 [ERROR] [system.err] ERROR: Caused by: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.scala.cobertura.CoberturaSensor
19:52:55.233 [ERROR] [system.err] ERROR: Caused by: org/sonar/plugins/cobertura/api/AbstractCoberturaParser
19:52:55.233 [ERROR] [system.err] ERROR: Caused by: org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.api.AbstractCoberturaParser
```

I tried searching for cause of the issue but could not find anything online. Please help me.

Comment: Full stacktrace would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It took me about a million years to find this, so I hope it's helpful to someone. This error is caused by updates to the sonar api that cause incompatibility with versions older than 4.5.

The solution is to use the updated version of the sonar scala plugin which is available here: https://github.com/1and1/sonar-scala

This built straight away for me and started analyzing scala without error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can update in your project and on your Sonar server.

**Go to your SonarQube Update Center**

Go to Administration -> System -> Update Center

[image: Update Center]

**Update the CorberturaSenor plugin**

As per this screenshot, find the specific plugin you are using and click update if available(This screenshot is showing a findbugs plugin but it will be the same concept for CorberturaSenor).

[image: CorberturaSenor]

**Update sonarqube dependency in your project**

This example is in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
     classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.1-rc1"
}
```

**Update sonar version**

This example is in Gradle

```
sonarqube {
     version='2.1-rc1'
}
```

**Update your CoberturaSensor plugin dependency in your project.**

Get the fully qualified name of your dependency you are using and search for a new version.  Then update it in your build tool.

Check here for more info on this error: [Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.*](http://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2016/08/error-with-gradle-build-sonarqube.html)